# LSTM Time Series for Predicting Next 24 Months

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, time-series, lstm

I already finish the prediction for my data with this datasets
[image]

and then dropping the Posting_Date, Material, and Qty to do LSTM:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
X =  Tab.drop(['Posting_Date', 'Material', 'Qty'],axis=1)
```

and then arranging and scaling the data

```
trainset,testset = X[0:-6].values, X[-6:].values

scal = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scal = scal.fit(trainset)

x_train =  trainset.reshape(trainset.shape[0],trainset.shape[1])
x_train = scal.transform(x_train)

x_test = testset.reshape(testset.shape[0], testset.shape[1])
x_test =  scal.transform(x_test)

x_train, y_train = x_train[:,1:], x_train[:,0:1]
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],1,x_train.shape[1])

x_test, y_test = x_test[:,1:], x_test[:,0:1]
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0],1,x_test.shape[1])
```

then performing the LSTM

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, batch_input_shape=(1,x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]), stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer = 'adam')
model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=100, batch_size = 1, verbose=2, shuffle=False)

y_prediction = model.predict(x_test, batch_size = 1)

import numpy as np
y_prediction = y_prediction.reshape(y_prediction.shape[0],1, y_prediction.shape[1])
#remake test set prediction
test_prediction = []

for index  in range(0, len(y_prediction)):
    np.concatenate([y_prediction[index], x_test[index]], axis=1)
    test_prediction.append(np.concatenate([y_prediction[index],x_test[index]], axis=1))

# #
test_prediction = np.array(test_prediction)
test_prediction = test_prediction.reshape(test_prediction.shape[0], test_prediction.shape[2])

inverse_test_prediction = scal.inverse_transform(test_prediction)

result_list = []
date_sales = list(Tab[-7:].Posting_Date)
act_sales = list(Tab[-7:].Qty)
```

Appending the LSTM result

```
for index in range(0, len(inverse_test_prediction)):
    result_dict = {}
    result_dict['Posting_Date'] = date_sales[index+1]
    result_dict['pred_Qty'] = int(inverse_test_prediction[index][0] + act_sales[index])
    result_list.append(result_dict)
df_result = pd.DataFrame(result_list)

df_result['Posting_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_result['Posting_Date'], dayfirst = True)
df_result
```

The result will be

[image]

The question is, how can this LSTM setting to be used for next 24 Months 2023-08-01 to 2025-08-01?

Thank you so much for helping me.